# trigger failure in jquery trigger 

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#but1").bind("click",function(e){
        alert(e.name);
    });

    jQuery("#but1").trigger({name:'Dmy', surname:'My'});
});
```

The alert fails to pass the data, why is that?!? the alert says 'undefined'.

What am I doing wrong, why I fail to pass the data?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RTXxY/23/) here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the values you pass to trigger come in as other parameters to the click handler, so you can't access it on the event object.  You need to accept an additional paramter.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#but1").bind("click",function(e, data){
        alert(data.name);
    });

    jQuery("#but1").trigger('click', {name:'Dmy', surname:'My'});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RTXxY/33/

Answer (score 1):

You have left out the `eventName` parameter for `trigger()`.

```
$('#but1').trigger('click', ['Dmy', 'My']);
```

API reference: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: why my other form is wrong... why cant I pass it as jason..? I dont want to pass it as an array..thanks for the solution,,it doesnt help much

Comment: You have not added eventName ('click'...) for trigger